# lftp mirror local content directory to remote

Tags: shell, lftp

I'm trying to upload files onto a server using lftp, and I want to specify a local folder, and upload all subfolders contained in this source folder, and not the folder itself.

I tried :

```
open -u username,password sftp://my.server:22 ; 
mirror -R -X *.json /local/folder/ /remote/directory ;
```

If locally :

```
local
└── folder
    ├── f1
    └── f2
```

After the mirror I've got remotely :

```
remote
└── directory
    └── folder
        ├── f1
        └── f2
```

And I want to have

```
remote
└── directory
    ├── f1
    └── f2
```

I tried to add/delete '*slash*' at the end of local and remote folder, but it changes nothing.
Is it possible to do what I want ?
I precise that I can't use rsync in this case.

Comment: cd into the local `./folder` dir and change your source dir spec to just `.` ? Good luck.

Comment: Your solution is so simple, why I didn't though about it ! I just used `lcd` to cd on local dir. With that I understood that my problem wasn't in the lftp command but in the folders inside the command, I used the wrong name for local folder. So it's working now ! Thanks !